# How to speed up reading lines from stream to memory?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, input, stream

I have about `1E6` lines in an input stream (from keyboard). Here's how I'm reading this:

```
int main () {
  ul n, in;
  scanf("%lu", &n);

  ul *a = new ul[n];

  while(n--){
    scanf("%lu", a+n);
  }
```

`n` is the number of lines to read. 
`ul` is `unsigned long` I defined somewhere else.

To clarify, the data is a bunch of integers (< `1E9`) separated by newline (`\n`) from input stream for keyboard.

This method is doing the job, but I want to speed it up. **I have thought about using buffers to read the whole stream to memory and parse**, but I can't figure out how to do it with C++ 11.

I am using `stdio.h` for reading streams since it appears to be faster than C++ stream readers. Otherwise, I would prefer C++ 11 solution.

Comment: “since it appears to be faster than C++ stream readers” – it’s not, this is a hard to kill myth. C and C++ streams are almost exactly on par, and in theory C++ streams can be faster (although I know of no implementation where this is reliably the case).

Comment: Hm, let's see. One million integers is not that bad. As text, it's probably a few dozen megs. It easily fits into RAM these days. You could initialize an `std::string` with `std::istreambuf_iterator`s in order to read the whole file into memory.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant That's not going to be the fastest solution.  The fastest solution will probably be to just `mmap`.

Comment: Did you try `std::copy` with `std::istream_iterator<ul>`?

Comment: @JamesKanze *probably* the fastest solution instead of guessing will be to just get it done first the easiest way, check if performance is acceptable, and only if not then wonder about optimization, preferably using a profiler.

Comment: Okay I just tried `std::copy(std::istream_iterator<ul>(std::cin), std::istream_iterator<ul>(), a)` and it is about 3.5 times slower than your `scanf` loop. Used g++ 4.8.2 with `-O3` on Ubuntu.

Comment: I did find a very simple solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976523/c-buffered-file-reading). Issue is, if I iterate over `10E6` lines with `10E9` characters each using a custom function, I would be going over `10E15` character `vector`, which is slow. I need something from C++ libraries like [numpy.fromfile](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html), which is efficient.

Comment: @BartoszKP That's certainly the correct way to go about it; in the end, what you need is not the fastest solution, but one that is adequately fast.  From experience, using `mmap` can improve performance, when it is necessary, and done correctly, isn't very difficult.  But of course, you should only drop `ifstream` _if_ you clearly have a performance problem.  (And when doing so, you should verify whether it is due to the conversions---some implementations aren't very good---or the data through put; `mmap` only helps for the latter.)

Comment: @prakharsingh95 On 'E' notation: 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation

In something like 1E6, the E represents "x10^". 10E6 is 1E7, and is not "one million", but "ten million". Please be careful with your notation.

Comment: @Andrew. Oops. I don't normally commit such stupid mistakes. Correcting.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can slightly increase performance by editing your while loop.

Since the numbers are less than 1e9 then you can read **int**, not **uns. long**.
In code below I read each character by **getc** and convert it to number myself.
Note that current_number is **int** 
In order to code to work you must modify your first  **scanf("%lu", &n);**  by reading  **'\n'** as well, i.e. your first scanf will be  **scanf("%lu\n", &n);**

```
while (n--) {
    int c = getc(stdin);
    int current_number = 0;
    do {
        current_number = (current_number << 1) + (current_number << 3) + (c - 48);
        c = getc(stdin);
    } while (c >= 48 && c <= 57);
    a[n] = current_number;
}
```

**scanf**  function works way more slower than **getc** on large data.
 **(current_number << 1) + (current_number << 3)**  is equivalent to  **current_number * 10** , but I don't think it is necessary. Modern compiler are able to figure out the best way to compute small operations. 
Good luck